# permalink /category/post-name with custom post type and taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I want to use custom post types with a custom taxonomy for different types of posts on my page. I have registered a custom post type called "portfolio" and a taxonomy for this post type.

```
function my_custom_post_portfolio() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Portfolio', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Portfolio-item', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'portfolio' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Item' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Item' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Item' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Items' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Item' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Items' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No items found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No items found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Portfolio'
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds our portfolio items',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies'    => array('category'),      
    'has_archive'   => true,
  );
  register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_portfolio' );    

function add_custom_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy('portfolioitems', 'portfolio', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Portfolioitems', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Item', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search items' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All items' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent item' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent item:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit item' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update item' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add new item' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New item name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'items' ),
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'portfolio',
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

I have template files for both of them, a archive-portfolio.php, the "starting page" of the portfolio posts, a single-portfolio.php for the display of the single portfolio item, and a taxonomy-portfolioitems.php for displaying all posts related to one "tag" (technically a custom taxonomy item)

It is working now fine, except that I get a 404 when trying to view the portfolio post. My permalink structure is:

/%category%/%postname%/

and I have the FV Top Level Categories plugin active to remove the "category" (like /category/portfolio/portfolio-post) from the url.

When I try to view my "normal" blog posts its working fine, the url is /blog/blog-categoryname/post-name

But my custom post type items give me 404 when trying to call /custom-post-type/post-name

(I have also a menu link called "portfolio" and its pointing to the category portfolio, which is registered with the custom post type.. could this be intefering somehow?)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Aaah I think I found the problem. Its somehow really intefering with each other, I changed the slug of my custom taxonomy to ` 'slug' => 'portfolio-tags',`and now its working! the "tags" of the portfolio are now displayed as /portfolio-tags/tag, but thats not so bad. Why is it like this? would be great if anybody could explain, eager to learn more

Comment: If your are using the same name/slug WP just can't know what is wanted, the post type archive or the tag archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said in your comment, the solution - in your case - was to change the slug of your custom taxonomy. The trouble you've been running into here is that you had no *distinct and unique permalink structure*. Namely, it has been unclear to WordPress if the *slug portfolio* is supposed to be the post type or tag archive, because of that it hasn't been able to chose a distinct procedure, like which template would be correct in this case, which leads to the an error like you described it.

Comment: thx somuch for the explanation!